# Activity recreate() flashes black screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-theme

I am using `activity.recreate()` to trigger a configuration change so I can load a new theme in `onCreate()` without loosing my fragments state (also I am showing a circular reveal animation for the new theme so I don't want any activity transition animation either).

It works fine on the emulator (Android 11) but on my real device (Pixel 3, Android 11), the screen turns black shortly before the activity is recreated. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Having same problem in physical device running Android 8, 10 and 11. I don't think this will ever be solved properly. The only two possible choices we have at the moment are to manually change every single color and text (like Telegram app does) or open the same Activity a second time and transition from the previous old Activity, but the problem with this one is there is no way to transfer any state. Neither option is viable for any reasonable developer nor worth the effort vs benefit.